# Running a python script in background using command prompt

Tags: python, process, background, command, prompt

I'm new to python, so my question may sound very absurd. Any help would be highly appreciated.

I'm running on windows system.

I have a python file sample.py that is a command line parser(made using argparse). The sample.py file in turn invokes many sub functions like compile,run etc based on parameters passed to file using command prompt.

```
#sample.py
<if command == complie>:call compile function(in another py file)
<if command == run>:call run function(in another py file)
```

To invoke the sample.py file:

```
cmd> python sample.py --Compile <argument list>
```

I want that after running above command, the command prompt is returned and python file does it work in background. Once the work is done i get message code compiled.

I want to this since the compile function will take some time and mean while i want to set-up other utilities using sample.py file.

Comment: You didn't tell us which OS you're using. In a Linux terminal (using Bash & its relatives), you just put `&` at the end of the command line. But I suspect that you're using Windows, so take a look at [How can I execute a Windows command line in background?](http://superuser.com/q/198525) on superuser.

Comment: If you are under linux you can use screen (http://www.greplinux.net/2013/04/screen-how-to-run-processes-in.html). The main advantage is to kept your code simple.

Comment: I presume you are using windows?

Comment: Correct i'm using Windows.@PM2Ring. I have tired adding & in the end but still i'm not able to see the control return to command prompt.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham correct i'm using windows.